# Bug with mod_rewrite and PHP?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I've run into a bug and I'm not sure of its source. I use mod_rewrite for the following:

```
 RewriteRule ^stuff$ index.php?page=stuff [L]
```

and it works just fine, but when I use

```
 RewriteRule ^(.+?)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

CSS is no longer applied to the page and the code doesn't seem to read GET requests.

Can someone elaborate on why this happens for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a rewrite condition to not rewite if the file is present & use the QSA flag to allow appended parameters:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your query strings have been converted into a directory-like structure, apache will check the directory if you are not using any path disclosure.

So if you're include the css file like so:
`<link href="skins/style.css">`

You'll need to disclose the full webpath to the file:

```
<link href="http://site.com/skins/style.css">`
```

Also, for all images in your css file you need to do the same, include the full webpath to avoid and issues when rewritting in the future.